# How to get page title using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to take page title and write it to a variable. 
I am using typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    title: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Title is " + this.title);
        this.title === document.title;
    }
}
```

But I am getting "Title is undefined" on a console.

I also tried:

```
 title: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.title === this.titleService.getTitle();
        console.log("Title is " + this.title);
    }
    public constructor(private titleService: Title) { }
    getTitle() {
        this.titleService.getTitle();
    }
```

but the result is the same. What is the correct way to get page title?

Comment: But have you set the document.title yet?

Comment: Yes I have title set in _Layoute.cshtml.  I am using this with .NET Core, but i don't think it is relevant to the question, is it?

Comment: `===` ? use a single `=`.

Comment: I am saying that if you get "indefined"  you may have not set it. document.title will give you the window title which is set in index.html

Comment: @Vega I understand just said to be clear. Thanks for quick help guys, it turns out it was rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made several mistakes.

1. `===` is used for Strict Equality Comparison, not for setting a value of a variable (more about `===` operator can be found here: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)).
2. You are first display variable, and after that trying to "set" (look at point 1) its value.

Change your code to:

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.title = document.title
      console.log(this.title)
 }
```

or:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this.titleService.getTitle();
    console.log("Title is " + this.title);
}
```

Comment: This look great but i got 

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined

How should i define it?

Comment: What about second approach? With `titleService` ?

Comment: To be honest I am surprised, that the first one did not. On my end, it is working without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Title provider from @angular/platform-browser. Refer to https://medium.com/@_ericmiller/setting-the-title-in-angular2-3c9379090527